# Would it be dangerous to use a charger with multiple voltage outputs to power a raspberry pi?

Tags: voltage, current, raspberry-pi

I have minimal understanding of electronics.

The charger I have (micro-usb) can output multiple voltages e.g. 5V at 3A or 9V at 2A.
From my understanding it is up to the device to negotiate which voltage will be supplied.
The raspberry pi can only handle up to 5.25V, and a 9V input would cause damage.

Is it safe to use such a charger?
Is there a possibility that the "negotiation" may fail for example in cases where even more amperage is needed, or perhaps default to 9V and harm the device?

Comment: @winny The related question has to do with phones that I suppose have different mechanisms that an rpi, and the explanation is too technical for me to understand. Could you perhaps tell me if a setup like the one I have described is safe for the rpi? I don't want to waste your time so a yes/no will suffice.

Comment: Don't worry, the higher voltages (e.g. +9V) have to be actively negotiated, otherwise it'll stay at ~5V.

Comment: @Velvet thank you very much!